# No shipping info with adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been able to get a PayPal adaptive payments payment to work with a simple payment call. 
But I want to get shipping details. 
I have tried setting action type to create, then using the payKey returned sending a SetPaymentOptions call setting RequireShippingAddressSelection = True, then using the returned url from the payment call as before but still no shipping info.

I have seen others with this problem but without an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Just looking into this myself - shipping info is returned on the `/payments/<PAYMENT_ID>/execute` endpoint. However if you do a get on the same payment after exection it still doesn't return the shipping info. Crazy!

Comment: It is nearly 2 days and I can`t find a way to  figure this out. Did you solve this problem? Were you able to provide shipping address during payment?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and here's what I got from PayPal Tech Support.

---

> It is not possible for you to supply a shipping address as part of an
>   Adaptive Payments transaction. However, you can request that the
>   customer selects a shipping address from the addresses existing on
>   their PayPal account when they checkout using the embedded flow.
>   Details of the embedded flow are available here:
>   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/
>   (Search for Embedded Payments)
>
> If you think this is an option you would also be required to implement
>   another API call, SetPaymentOptions, which would be sent after the Pay
>   API request. Within the SetPaymentOptions API request you would add
>   the parameter requireShippingAddressSelection. Details of the
>   SetPaymentOptions API are located here:
>   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/
>
> If your application requires that you supply a custom shipping address
>   to PayPal at the time of payment then you will need to consider using
>   Express Checkout instead of Adaptive Payments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the shipping info isn't passing?  I don't think it's anything you'll see during the checkout process, but it will show up in the transaction details of the payment in your PayPal account.

Comment: According to the documentation it should create a dropdown with Address selection [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#idb1e25ba9-24fb-4466-bd80-9c9420d010f2__id783d089a-4baf-4674-9c65-7491b4bee6e2) see here

Comment: @user971374 - I'm having the same problem. I'm passing in `SenderOptions.requireShippingAddressSelection => true`, but it never asks me to select a delivery address (nor does **GetShippingAddresses** seems to return anything back either). I wish they're docs were better explained... it seems like one thing after another :/

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours researching this and it appears to be an API bug from 2011 (great job PayPal!).

Unfortunately, you have to request the shipping info from the user before redirecting them to PayPal.

[Source link](http://thebesthacker.com/question/how-do-you-get-the-shipping-address-back-from-an-adaptive-payment-api-call.html)